# if match found delete from Multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet 0 : https://paste.pics/82a491cbc642d6fff555ef70612aec5b

Sheet 1 : https://paste.pics/cafe8628b76e56789cf03b06a923bde8

Sheet 2 : https://paste.pics/2320369d395a22c868b5e439b456ad3a

Sheet 3 : https://paste.pics/9fc84c7f43e1a2819d1537593c44c1f9

If match is found => **"SUP" "AL" "AP"** then Data should be cleared from all the sheets with one Button click 
Button is in "Sheet0" => when clearing data the Headers should not get Cleared

if want to see my excel safe download 100%
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0n_srbhF02OhiWzKsB4IWWiwV5nO-Vl/view?usp=sharing

=========================================================================
This is my code where i tried But not working giving error at **Ws.Range**

```
Private Sub CommandCreate_new_Click()
      Dim Ws As Worksheet
      For Each Ws In Sheets(Array("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"))
         Ws.Range ("I9:AM9")
        .Cells.Replace what:=UCase("SUP"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=True
        .Cells.Replace what:=UCase("SUP"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False
        .Cells.Replace what:=UCase("AL"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=True
        .Cells.Replace what:=UCase("AL"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next Ws   End Sub
```

========================================================================

**Partially Working But not setting the Cell to => No fill Color [As match condition is found data should be deleted and even the cell color should be deleted and set to no fill color]**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Dim Ws As Worksheet
      For Each Ws In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
         Ws.Range("A4", Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
         Ws.Range("B4", Ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
         Ws.Range("C4", Ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
         Ws.Range("D4", Ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
         Ws.Range("E4", Ws.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
         Ws.Range("F4", Ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
         Ws.Range("G4", Ws.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
         Ws.Range("H4", Ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
         Ws.Range("I4", Ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
         Ws.Range("J4", Ws.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).ClearContents
      Next Ws
End Sub
```

This is the below output i am getting after running the above partially code

[My output][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EbRP.png

Comment: What does "not working" stand for, specifically? Are you getting any errors? Where?

Comment: basically i need to clear only those which matches and set to no fill color i have to manually set the each cell to no fill color after erasing data

Comment: You can set fill color to none using `yourRangeHere.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`  Also - to echo @MathieuGuindon's question - What happens when you run your code?  "not working" is not a useful description of that.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon's and @ Tim Williams Please have look at the Above updated question i have attached the output which i am getting